# How do I use an "if" statement to delete a clone of a gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use an if statement in order to clear all of the clones in my scene while my game is running, but when I added my "if" statement it does nothing at all.

I've tried to add `Gameobject.` to the clone in the parenthesis but it doesn't do anything except give me an error saying that "Gameobject" doesn't exist in the current context.

This is the "if" statement:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            Destroy(clone);
        }
```

As said above, the if statement is supposed to clear all of the clones in the scene except for the original, but it doesn't make a difference at all.

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question for us to help you. What type is `clone`? Where is this monobehaviour defined? How do you differentiate between the clone and the original? Are you using `GameObject` instead of your claimed `Gameobject` - as only one of these exists (unless you defined it as something else, then we need to know). I'm sure I can think of plenty of other questions - but instead, I think you should consider giving us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, but I think I understand enough to answer.

First off, your claim that your "if" statement does nothing at all is false and misleading. If you get an error after pressing the Alpha2 button, that means that the code tried successfully to execute whatever is in the if statement.

The problem lies in the fact that your Gameobject clone is unassigned. The variable is like an empty shell, or a husk that can contain and point to a gameobject you have inside the game.

Here's a very simple piece of code to do the behavior you described:

```cs
[SerializeField] Gameobject clonePrefab; //You have to drag and drop a prefab from Unity here
List<Gameobject> clones=new List<Gameobject>();

void Start(){
    for(i=0,i<10,i++){
        clones.Add(Instantiate(clonePrefab));
    }
}

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            for(i=0,i<clones.Count,i++){
                Destroy(clones[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: *`[SerializeField]`* Or you could just make it `public`